# XAML designer cannot resolve references using custom implementation of ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make use of the SharedResourceDictionary [from this tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html). This class derives from ResourceDictionary, but loads content only once even if it is referenced multiple times. It works like a charm when I build and run it.

However, any styles referenced using a SharedResourceDictionary will cause a compiler error in the XAML designer:

> The resource "X" could not be resolved.

This error does not occur when I simply switch SharedResourceDictionary to ResourceDictionary.

The reference `{StaticResource LightGreenBrush}` in the following example will cause an error, even though it is defined in ColorDictionary.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <SharedResourceDictionary Source="pack://Application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/ResourceDictionaries/ColorDictionary.xaml"/>
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightGreenBrush}"/>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Is there any way to prevent this error from showing on (what seems to be) perfectly valid XAML?

Comment: <Style TargetType="Button"> ?

Comment: The same error still occurs. It's very unlikely something is wrong with the styles because they work perfectly and give no error when using ResourceDictionary.

Comment: Any luck with this? I am running into the same issue.